# Unexpected behavior with the Node.js Stream API

Tags: node.js, parsing, csv, filestream, piping

I try to pipe a CSV file through a parser, delete a row given an ID, pipe the new array to a stringifier then finally output the result into a new CSV.

The problem is that the new array is not returned properly. I mean, I manage to delete the row but not to return the new CSV.

Here is the [CSV file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=80114922678112333632)

And here is the code:

```
'use strict';


const Fs    = require('fs');
const Csv   = require('csv');


let input  = 'data_stack.csv';
let output = 'data_output.csv';


let readStream  = Fs.createReadStream(input);
let writeStream = Fs.createWriteStream(output);

let opt  = {delimiter: ',', quote: '"', escape: '"', relax: true, skip_empty_lines: true};

function deleteRow (id) {

    return Csv.parse(opt, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let delId = [];
        // The row corresponding to the id is pushed to an array to console.log it. The other rows are returned 
        let newData = data.filter(line => {
            if (line[0] === id) {
                delId.push(line);
            }
            else {
                return line;
            }
        });

        if (delId !== 0) {
            console.log("Deleted line\n");
            console.log(delId);
        }

        // Testing if the row was deleted
        let result = [];
        // If the row is not deleted, push it into the result array
        newData.forEach(line => {
            if (line[0] === id) {
                result.push(line);
            }
        });
        // "Not found !" is console logged. The row has been deleted 
        if (result.length !== 0) {
            console.log(result);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not found !");
        }

        return newData;
    });
}

readStream.pipe(deleteRow('566150121ae803f53751c3f2'))
```

This code is working
But if I choose to return the newData array to pipe it the a stringifier then to output the result to a CSV file, I get 2 unexpected behaviors:

1. The delId array is now empty and I don't know why
2. The output file is created but the row that was deleted before is still present in the output file

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';


const Fs    = require('fs');
const Csv   = require('csv');


let input  = 'data_stack.csv';
let output = 'data_output.csv';


let readStream  = Fs.createReadStream(input);
let writeStream = Fs.createWriteStream(output);

let opt  = {delimiter: ',', quote: '"', escape: '"', relax: true, skip_empty_lines: true};

function deleteRow (id) {

    return Csv.parse(opt, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let delId = [];
        // The row corresponding to the id is pushed to an array to console.log it. The other rows are returned 
        let newData = data.filter(line => {
            if (line[0] === id) {
                delId.push(line);
            }
            else {
                return line;
            }
        });

        if (delId !== 0) {
            console.log("Deleted line\n");
            console.log(delId);
        }

        // Testing if the row was deleted
        let result = [];
        // If the row is not deleted, push it into the result array
        newData.forEach(line => {
            if (line[0] === id) {
                result.push(line);
            }
        });
        // "Not found !" is console logged. The row has been deleted 
        if (result.length !== 0) {
            console.log(result);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not found !");
        }

        return newData;
    });
}

let stringifier = Csv.stringify({quoted: true});

readStream.pipe(deleteRow('566150121ae803f53751c3f2')).pipe(stringifier).pipe(writeStream);
```

I don't really understand how piping the result from the deleteRow function affect its behavior.

Any advise ?

Answer (score 0):

`csv.parse` has [2 APIs](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/):

1. Callback (buffer) based and;
2. Streams based.

If you pass the callback function, as you are doing on your example, you are subscribing to the callback API, which means the whole parsed data in its entirety is available to you via the `data` argument.

However, that callback is a stream 'sink', meaning that any modification to the data will not make it down to your `writeStream`.

You'll need to adjust the code to either use the callback API, like this:

```
function deleteRow(readStream, id, done) {
  readStream.pipe(Csv.parse(opt, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return done(err);

    // Wrire new data to file
    Csv.stringify(data.filter(line => line[0] !== id))
      .pipe(writeStream)
      .on('end', done);
  }));
}

deleteRow(readStream, '5660d7e11ae803f53751aeb0', function (err) {
  console.log('done!');
});
```

Or, utilize the streams API like this:

Comment: @Ixe, you forgot the end of your post. Can you add it so I can compare to be sure I fully understand